# i want the search button to do nothing when i click the search button it should shown no error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, barcode

the textbox is empty i want no error when i click the search button[image]

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-IPS9HAF\\JUSTINEVILLATEST;Initial Catalog=School_Records;User ID=zidex_server;Password=killerblade");

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select * from Students_Record where SchoolID= '" + int.Parse(ID_Number1.Text) + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader srd = comm.ExecuteReader();
        while (srd.Read())
        {
            GetFirstName.Text = srd.GetValue(1).ToString();
            GetLastName.Text = srd.GetValue(2).ToString();
            Course.Text = srd.GetValue(3).ToString();
            YearLevel.Text = srd.GetValue(4).ToString();
            Address.Text = srd.GetValue(5).ToString();
            Contact_Number.Text = srd.GetValue(6).ToString();
            Position_box.Text = srd.GetValue(8).ToString();
            Vaccinated_Box.Text = srd.GetValue(9).ToString();

            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(srd.GetSqlBytes(10).Buffer);
            Getting_Picture.Image = Image.FromStream(mem);
        }
        con.Close();

    }
```

```
this is the search button
```

Comment: Which operation throws that exception?  What are the runtime values used in that operation?

Comment: can you try to add a `try catch` block around your code to see what error is occurring?  there are a few possibilities for what could go wrong in this scenario.

try {
   /// your code
} catch(System.Exception ex) {
       // add a breakpoint here!
      System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError($"Error Connecting: {ex}");
}

Answer (score 3):

Within the btn event handler, just add a validation check: if there is no text in the TextBox in question, simply return and do nothing

```cs
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ID_Number1.Text)) return;

    //... rest of your logic that is meant to happen where there actually is text
}
```

I also recommend the use of `int.TryParse()` rather than `int.Parse(ID_Number1.Text)`. This becomes another validation check

```cs
if (!int.TryParse(ID_Number1.Text, out int id1)) return;

//... now everything is validated, do the SQL query using id1
```

Comment: This is correct. Validate your inputs